# How to connect a bluetooth stereo headset to my laptop

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

Anybody can help me to connect my bluetooth stereo headset. I'm using samsung SF410 laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium

Answer (score 1):

Put your headset into pairing mode (consult its manual) and add the bluetooth device from the control panel.

From the start menu's search box start typing "bluetooth" and you'll find it.

Comment: quick google:http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/laptops/NP-SF410-A01US-specs    Your laptop does not have bluetooth built in. You have to buy a usb bluetooth dongle.